# Array inside an array using JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is code in JAVA I used JSONArray and method `JSONarray.put(string);`

```
public JSONArray getChart() {
    Connection con = getConnectionObject();
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    JSONObject jCharto = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();



    try {
        st = con.createStatement();         
        String query  = "select count(books_issued) as books_issued,command from fact_aaglib, school where fact_aaglib.school_name = school.school_name group by command;";


        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("['Command','Book Issued'],");
         while (rs.next())  
                {                                                                                                   

                String zone = rs.getString("command");
                arr.put(zone);

                int booksissued = rs.getInt("books_issued");

                arr.put(booksissued);


                }
         System.out.println(arr+",");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}   
return arr; 
}
```

Here is my output

```
['Command','Book Issued'],["Central",324,"Southern",312,"South-West",192,"Eastern",264,"Northern",84,"Western",396],
```

But actual I want output like this:

```
[
    ['Command', 'Books Issued'],
    ["Central",324],["Southern",312],
    ["South-West",192], 
    ["Eastern",264], 
    ["Northern",84],
    ["Western",396]
]
```

And this data is using in google charts to draw bar chart .

Comment: `Javascript` != `Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JSONArray` is not limited to strings.

You need to create one array for holding records, then create a new one for each pair or records. Here is the basic idea:

```
// create the "top" array
JSONArray topArray = new JSONArray();

// add your static "headers"
JSONArray headers = new JSONArray();
headers.put("Command");
headers.put("Book Issued");
topArray.put(headers);

while (rs.next()){   
    // create a new array for the current record
    JSONArray recordArray = new JSONArray(); 
    // populate the record array                                                                                             
    String zone = rs.getString("command");
    recordArray.put(zone);
    int booksissued = rs.getInt("books_issued");
    recordArray.put(booksissued);

    // append the record array to the top array
    topArray.put(recordArray);
}

return topArray;
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Derlin for fast reply...

**Actually Output coming like this:**

`[["Central",324],
["Southern",312],
["South-West",192],
["Eastern",264],
["Northern",84],
["Western",396]]`

**I want output like this:**

`[
           ['Command', 'Books Issued'],
           ["Central",324],
           ["Southern",312],
           ["South-West",192],
           ["Eastern",264],
           ["Northern",84],
           ["Western",396]
           ] `

Thank You

Comment: If there is just the first array missing, add it before the `while` (see updated answer). (and by the way, it is miss Derlin ^^)